# Find what causes a re-direct when a button is clicked

Tags: debugging, redirect, kohana

Is there a way of finding what is causing a re-direct when a particular link is clicked. I have a kohana site with thousands of files and it would be near impossible to find where the code that makes the re-direct. The link is: http://www.loosediamonds.diamgs.com/shoppingbag and the redirect happens when the "checkout" button is clicked.

I have seen the link in the source code and it explicitly points to http://www.loosediamonds.diamgs.com/checkout/signin so there must be something that causes the jump to http://diamgs.com/

I'm hoping there is a bit of software that can trace anything linked to that button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect is performed by Konana by:

1. Calling `HTTP::redirect()`
2. Throwing corresponding redirect HTTP_Exception_ (By default HTTP_Exception_302)
3. Redirecting within `HTTP_Exception_Redirect::location()` method.

So to check where has redirect appeared I'd set `Kohana::$environment` to `DEVELOPMENT`, redifine `HTTP_Exception_Redirect::location()` method, interrupting it just before actual issuing `Location` header and use `parent::get_response();` method to display nice default Kohana Exception page. This page should include Exception stack trace in which you'll see where does redirect was called.